# Sqlite rollback after commit

Tags: sqlite, commit, rollback

In Sqlite3, is there a way to rollback to a point after committing a transaction?
If you are wondering why I am committing a statement if I am not sure, the reason is that I am using Sqlite from inside a C++ interface, which only saves to the file if I commit the transaction.

Comment: No, there isn't. And of course it only saves when you commit a transaction; committing is the act of saving the data you just wrote.

Comment: Thanks @ColonelThirtyTwo. As you might guess, my purpose is to test my database in another code. So the workflow is: (i) Update db. (ii) Test it in another environment. (iii) Undo if not passed. In this regard, I believe the best solution is to duplicate the db file before I change it and use to replace the updated one if it fails the test. Have a better idea?

Comment: You could use nested transactions with `SAVEPOINT` and `RELEASE` (http://sqlite.org/lang_savepoint.html).

Comment: @Googie, Committing a transaction also disables a savepoint.

Comment: @emre, when working with nested transactions, one should avoid using `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` and switch entirely to `SAVEPOINT` / `RELEASE`.

Comment: @Googie, as I told in my question, I have to commit in order for the changes to be effective since I am using sqlite from inside a C++ interface.

Comment: @emre, I don't understand what you mean with the "from inside a C++ interface". Are you trying to commit transaction, then read commited data from other database connection and then rollback the previously commited transaction? The most important thing is - do you want to do anything with the data you commited, or you just want to commit it and then roll it back again?

Comment: @Googie, maybe I used the wrong words, sorry. I mean I use sqlite through a C++ interface, not directly. And yes, my database has another connection. So, I need to commit the change, let the other connection check if everything is OK with the committed data, and rollback if there is a problem. I just want to be able to commit the data and roll it back in some cases. For instance, I may want to add a row to a table. Check if the new row is fine. If not, I want to roll back to the state where there wasn't a row. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: In that case I see no other option than to make a copy of the database before commiting transaction. To do copy I suggest to use `sqlite3_backup_*()` functions family, as they guarantee an operation to be atomic. If you have big database and you want to do this only with 1 table (this tricky "rollback"), then you should keep the table in a separate database and `ATTACH` it when used, so you can backup only the database with a single table.

Comment: @Googie, this is actually a nice solution. I have already tried making a copy of the database and worried about the instability. It looks like the sqlite_backup_*() feature solves that problem either. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a copy of the database before commiting transaction. To do copy I suggest to use `sqlite3_backup_*()` functions family, as they guarantee an operation to be atomic.

If you have big database and you want to do this only with 1 table (this tricky "rollback"), then you should keep the table in a separate database and `ATTACH` it when used, so you can backup only the database with a single table.